# XStream issue with implicit collections

Tags: java, xml, xstream, oxm

I have the following XML:

```
<appConfig>
    <database isSource="true" fizz="129"/>
    <database isSource="false" fizz="29494" />
    <buzz bee="always" />
</appConfig>
```

That should map to the following POJOs:

```
public class AppConfig {
    private Database sourceDb;
    private Database targetDb;
    private Buzz buzz;
}

public class Database {
    // Omitted for brevity...
}

public class Buzz {
    // Omitted for brevity...
}
```

And have configured the following `XStream` mapper:

```
XStream oxMapper = new XStream();
oxMapper.alias("appConfig", AppConfig.class);
oxMapper.alias("database", Database.class);
oxMapper.alias("buzz",  Buzz.class);
```

To read and deserialize the XML like so:

```
ApplicationConfig appCfg = (ApplicationConfig)oxMapper.fromXML(
        getXMLSnippet());
```

But am getting this error:

```
Element database of type com.myapp.Database is not defined as field in type com.myapp.AppConfig
```

I read [this article](http://off-topic.biz/en/conversionexception-when-parsing-xml-with-xstream-element-is-not-defined/) which talks about implicit collections, and *believe* that XStream thinks my two `Database` items are a part of a list (implicit collection) when in fact they are not (they should map to 2 different `AppConfig` properties).

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set aliases by the *name* of field, not the type.
For your example it should be:

```
oxMapper.alias("sourceDb", Database.class);
oxMapper.alias("targetDb", Database.class);
oxMapper.alias("buzz",  Buzz.class);
```